# Declaring multiple numbers together makes the first one 'undefined' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I declare multiple variables together in JavaScript, the first one always becomes 'undefined':

```
let x, y = 0;
//undefined
typeof x
//"undefined"
typeof y
//"number"
```

**Why does this happen?**

Only solution seems to be to declare them in separate lines:

```
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
//number
typeof x
//"number"
typeof y
//"number"
```

(All code is running in Google Chrome Console)

[image]

[image]

Comment: ``let x, y = 0`` is equivalent to ``let x; let y = 0;``. You need to do this: ``let x = 0, y = 0;``.

Comment: when you say `let x, y = 0;`, you are declaring **x** variable without assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define the value for x

`let x=0,y=0;` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this: let x = 0, y = 0;.
Because
let x, y = 0 is equal to let x ; let y = 0;.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin is right in his comment, but if you wish to assign a whole bunch of variables, and don't want to write `= 0` every time, you can first define the variables, then assign them all at the same time.

```js
let x, y, z, a, b, c;
x = y = z = a = b = c = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment Operator has Left to Right associativity so first the rightmost operand gets assigned the value and then the operator left has no value to assigned and as in javascript there is no way to know the `type` of a variable at compile time hence `x` which has no value assigned will have no type assigned to it thus yielding `undefined`.

More on associativity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)